# Information System Security Assessment Framework (ISSAF) out of date?

Tags: penetration-test

I've stumbled across an article about pentest standards and among others there was one called  Information System Security Assessment Framework (ISSAF) which attracted my attention. Maybe someone can bring me more information on this standard and why is it still used?
I might be mistaken but if we  look at the release date we can see year 2005?

Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: It's used because it is useful? No framework is perfect, and age is not usually a factor for frameworks. You use the framework that provides the foundation you need. Mix and match as you need.